# SSRS missing values in tablix

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS (both 2008 and 2016 are doing the same thing) is not showing values. I have a column "Status" with three different possible values. Every row is populated in the result set of my query in SSMS. But in the SSRS tablix, more than half of the rows are blank.

Comment: Do the rows that are blank have the same one of the three possible values?

Comment: No, each one of the possible values has one or more blanks.

Comment: Yes, the three values are "Recruitment In Progress", "Recruitment Complete", "Recruitment Not Started". Just a simple tablix value, no matrices. -data type is varchar

Comment: So this is the crazy thing, the values show up in both SSMS and the SSRS query designer, but not the tablix. I've resorted to just loading them into a staging table and running the report from there --- values will then populate the tablix.

Comment: A picture of your design view might help. You may not have the rep to embed a pic but you can just add the link to the imgur page.

Comment: Daniel, no parameters, no filters.

Comment: Not possible unless you are doing something to manipulate data in between using expressions etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 'group by' in your sql query, try removing it or change the order. Make sure it is in the right order of grouping. For example in my query, I had the following grouping

Group by Year, Measures, ProgramID, Program

This was giving me the same issue because the right order for the data was

Group by Year, ProgramID, Program, Measures